# Best practice when using rest clients in a servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I am working on a project where we have a big portal running in a tomcat container. Every time the user logs into the portal, some information is retrieved by invoking a rest client. The code looks something like this:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static final String REST_URI = "http://url.tld/to/login/api";

    private Client client;

    public Client getClient() {
        if (client == null) {
            client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        }
        return client;
    }

    public LoginData getLoginData(int userId) {
        return client
          .target(REST_URI)
          .path(String.valueOf(userId))
          .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .get(LoginData.class);
    }

}
```

I am using Apache CXF as my jax-rs client implementation. As far as I know the client object should be thread safe, so that shouldn't be a problem. But imagine 10000 users are opening the website simultaneously and for each request the above code is executed. Do I get a performance problem? Do I need more than just one client object, maybe a client pool?

Comment: No, but there may be something internal that you can configure with `ClientBuilder`. I suggest reading the documentation.